# Opc data change event not fired C#

Tags: c#, events, memory, opc

I'm creating a C# app which needs to communicate with PLCs. I'm using Kepserver with OPCAutomation.dll.

Code :

```
public void Create()
{
    OPCAutomation.OPCGroup oGroup1 = this._oServer.OPCGroups.Add("Group1");

    oGroup1.DeadBand = 0;
    oGroup1.UpdateRate = 100;
    oGroup1.IsSubscribed = true;
    oGroup1.IsActive = true;

    oGroup1.OPCItems.AddItem("Channel1.Plc1.Group1.Tag1", 1);
    oGroup1.OPCItems.AddItem("Channel1.Plc1.Group1.Tag2", 2);
    ...

    oGroup1.DataChange += new OPCAutomation.DIOPCGroupEvent_DataChangeEventHandler(Notify);
}

public void Notify(int TransactionID, int ModifiedTagsCount, ref Array ClientHandles, ref Array ItemValues, ref Array Qualities, ref Array TimeStamps)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Notification!");
}
```

My problem is if there is just this block of code in my app, everythings work well but as soon as I add some of other code (no links with OPC) like creating others classes etc..., I don't receive notifications anymore and I don't know why...

To verify it, I simply did that after initializing of the OPC part :

```
List<RandomClass> test = new List<RandomClass>();

for (int i = 0; i < 9999; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    test.Add(new RandomClass());
    Task.Delay(10).Wait();
}
```

I received notifications at start but after reaching a particular number of i (1XXX in average and almost the same number at each app start), no more notifications received and I don't know why.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You should avoid using Task.Delay(10).Wait() within a loop, as this can block the current thread. Instead, use asynchronous programming to avoid blocking. You can use async/await to introduce delays without blocking the thread -> await Task.Delay(10);.

public async Task RunOpcAsync()
{
    Create();
    await Task.Yield();
}
Task.Run(RunOpcAsync);